# Update SharePoint Online User Profile Properties (SPS-Birthday) via Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile-service, user-profile-property, bulk

our current on-prem enviorment uses a external field to hold the employees birthday, this is then mapped to SPS-Birthday (on-prem). We have a SP Online instance to and I would like to get this birthday field to the online instance as well. I have exported a JSON list of the user account and the property field I need from SharePoint 2016 however I am struggling to import this into SharePoint Online with the [provided API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/pnp_articles/bulk-user-profile-update-api-for-sharepoint-online). The modified powershell runs successfully however the field is not being updated:

```
$adminUrl = "...admin.sharepoint.com" 
$userName = "..."
$pwd = Read-Host -Prompt 'Enter your password' -AsSecureString
$importFileUrl = "...Test%20Document%20Library/sample.txt"

$uri = New-Object System.Uri -ArgumentList $adminUrl
$context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($uri)

$context.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $pwd)
$o365 = New-Object Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.Office365Tenant($context)
$context.Load($o365)

$userIdType=[Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.TenantManagement.ImportProfilePropertiesUserIdType]::Email

$userLookupKey="IdName"

$propertyMap = New-Object -type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[String,String]'
$propertyMap.Add("Property1", "Office")
$propertyMap.Add("Property2", "SPS-Birthday")

$workItemId = $o365.QueueImportProfileProperties($userIdType, $userLookupKey, $propertyMap, $importFileUrl);

$context.ExecuteQuery();

Write-Host "Import job created with following identifier:" $workItemId.Value
```

This is the sample file being used, I have tried using Birthday in 2 different formats and still nothing.

```
{
"value": [
    {
        "IdName": "email1@.com",
        "Property1": "JHB",
        "Property2": "1/11/2016  12:00:00 AM"
    },
    {
        "IdName": "email2@.com",
        "Property1": "JHB",
        "Property2": "1/13/2016  12:00:00 AM"
    },
    {
        "IdName": "email3@.com",
        "Property1": "JHB",
        "Property2": "January 14"
    }
]}
```

Really come to a roadblock with this and the help would be greatly apriciated please guys. Regards.

Comment: Just a small update on a recent discovery, I created another user property field to attempt the same script above (of type string). The script successfully updated this new field I had added but not the SPS-Birthday one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Again thank you Viraj, I have added the solution here which has been scripted to extract from SharePoint 2016 and insert into SharePoint Online with no user interaction needed (other than basic variable setup) and into the correct format on my [Github](https://github.com/soprono/SharePoint-PowerShell/tree/master/Updating%20User%20Profile%20Properties%20(Birthday))

In proper prospects of a answer the format I needed was MM/DD/YYYY.

Answer (score 2):

Try to add date in following format

```
$converteddate = "{0:MMM dd}" -f [datetime]$birthdate
```

Comment: Attempting that now Viraj, will update you on the feedback. The only issue there is adjusting the json extraction to get the date into that format. Once SP-Online refreshed Ill let you know the result.

Comment: First, tyy with hard coded date.

Comment: Shall do, Just executed the script, thanks Viraj will post feedback as soon as I see any changes.

Comment: Doesnt seem like the different formatting working. I could be wrong and missed the update cycle by a few minutes so Ill just keep checking for today and report back.

Comment: Hey Viraj, the test ran overnight and still no luck with that format.

Comment: SPS-Birthday is display name, what is internal name of this property? Have you tried with it?

Comment: I was under the impression that SPS-Birthday is the internal property name and Birthday is the display name.

 Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Property Names [Birthday] cannot be found in User Profiles."
At line:1 char:1

Comment: Updated date format, this will work.

Comment: Mind elaborating on that please Viraj.

Comment: Follow this link: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d1984faf-edd8-4d73-b3ec-032abd07414f/update-birthday-in-user-profile-using-powershell-is-not-working?forum=sharepointdevelopment

Comment: Still no luck on this, think I might need to elevate this issue as the way the above script is called does not allow you to edit the specific date value before it is inserted.

Comment: First, try to add hard coded birthday for single user using power shell, you can find issue easily. If you wait for 1 day, i don't think you can resolve this problem in your time.

Comment: I have tried dates in the following ways: "DEC 7", "7 DEC", "December 7", "7 December", "2016-12-07T00:00:00Z", "2016-12-07" with no success.

Comment: The following format worked for me MM/dd/2000. I am busy modifying the export and import script process then will update the question with the final solution. Thank you Viraj for the guidance and opening my mind up to possible formats.

Comment: Great.  Finally you got the solution. I am happy with that